# How can I guess the charset of an html document?

Tags: html, xml, character-encoding, html-parsing

Some malformed and incomplete HTML pages have no charset information assigned to them, and I have to figure out how to display them. Since there are dozens of encoding systems, I wonder if there is an algorithm I can use to correctly perform this task. Is there such thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [jchardet](http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/) or [chsdet](http://chsdet.sourceforge.net/index.php).
Character set detection is probabilistic so it may go wrong in some cases, I have used jchardet with success few years back.